# IIS 5 & ASP.NET MVC Directory Browsing Problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

We configured IIS 5 by mappping * to asp.net handler so that ASP.NET MVC works. After configuring this, directory browsing is not working.

Also uploadify jquery plugin is not working. Showing IO error 2038.

Can someone please suggest us how to enable directory browsig with ASP.NET MVC configurations on IIS 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you'll be able to get directory browsing to work with ASP.NET MVC in the same application.  When you added the wildcard mapping, you told ASP to handle every request.  If the request doesn't map to an actual file, it will try to match a route in MVC.  If there isn't a matching controller with an index (assuming that's your default) action, then it will fail.

My suggestion is to split your web site into "application" and "content".  Set up the application as a separate web site and apply the wildcard mapping there.  Leave your content with the original configuration.  I don't use IIS5 any more -- with one exception on an old XP development box -- I'm afraid that can't really be of more help.

If I were you, though, I'd upgrade to a more recent OS and web server.  Expecting new technology to work on a decade-old platform is very optimistic.